# Is Mathjax accessible for people using screen readers?

Tags: support, mathjax, accessibility

I tried writing a formula on [Why are some equations and formulas written in a way that suggests the smaller number divides the bigger number, instead of the other way around?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104765/why-are-some-equations-and-formulas-written-in-a-way-that-suggests-the-smaller-n), but I cannot find the option to show math as when I use shift F10. All I see is a context menu for my web browser. The dollar signs and formula show up as raw text. However, my screen reader can read Math ML and display it in Nemeth code in Braille using MathPlayer by Design Science for those have who converted it.

Comment: Note that MathML appears under the MathJax menu (right click on any such math formula) in two different ways.  The first is under "Show Math As" as "MathML Code", which is probably of little relevance since it applies only to the one formula clicked on.  The second is under "Math Settings > Math Renderer" where one can choose (for the given website) to have math formulas rendered to the browser as MathML.  This seems most likely to provide the screen reader software with a consistent interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MathJax provides an accessibility extension that works with a variety of screen readers. For more details concerning MathJax and screen readers, I suggest reading [this link on accessibility features in MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/misc/accessibility-features.html). Often this is through MathML, as MathJax translates expressions to MathML internally.

I am uncertain how one should use a screen reader to check a MathJax expression while it is being written.

For those who are not sighted, what happens is that there is an input text area, and below that there is a preview area. When a user types a latex expression, it remains plaintext in the input area, but below MathJax renders that text as a math image. This preview area also renders markdown syntax and a few other formatting things specific to StackExchange. I think that this means that in order to use MathJax's MathML when writing a math expression, one would need to navigate to the expression in the preview pane. Unfortunately, I don't know of a good way to do that.

Comment: As you point out, the main question is about the editor. Since MathJax is not involved in that part, the question is less about MathJax and more about stackexchange's editor. FWIW, It's difficult to create an accessible equation authoring experience on the web (e.g., incomplete TeX strings causing all kinds of useless errors). For a complex, hacky solution, only dealing with simple equation layout, Desmos is a good example.

Comment: The combination of MathML as the MathJax renderer + "Fast Preview" seems to result in "raw" $\LaTeX$ strings being emitted into my non-MathML enabled (Chromium for Linux) browser.  It's possible that the underlying XML encoding is present but ignored as lacking significance as XHTML markup.

Comment: The link in the post seems to be dead, here is [some version from the Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20190102083804/http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/misc/accessibility-features.html). I suppose the new link is this: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/accessibility.html ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20191224234651/http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/accessibility.html)).

Comment: for a post about accessibility perhaps leaving a dead link in the body and archived and potentially updated links to be (hopefully) discovered in the third comment below it is a suboptimal scenario?